# get the timestamp in java

Tags: java, timestamp, gregorian-calendar

I wanto to get the timestamp and add 5 sec to it. I tried this code

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2007, 9 - 1, 23);

               int period = Integer.parseInt(5);
               cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, period);
               long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();

               String timeStamp = String.valueOf(millis);
```

But I always get the same result 1190498405000, even one hour later.

Edit:
I tried this code but I'am not sure if its correct

```
java.util.Calendar cal2 = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
                System.out.println("Instance before : "+ cal2.getTimeInMillis());
                cal2.add(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 5);

                System.out.println("Instance after : "+ cal2.getTimeInMillis());
```

> Instance before : 1390784737521
>   Instance after :  1390784742521

So the before it's the exactly time and the second one it's + 5 secondes ?

Comment: Please post code that compiles.

Comment: You're seeding the calendar with the same time each time, so wouldn't you expect it to return the same result?

Comment: Define "time stamp".  Time in Java is generally the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  `Date` (including `Calendar`, `java.sql.Timestamp` and other date/time components) in the default API have no sense of formatting.

Comment: I'd be really worried if you didn't get the same result from the same calculation when you did it an hour later.  I am counting on `2+2` still being `4` tomorrow.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @user567 Your question is confused. Do you want (a) the current date and time (now, today) or do you want (b) a date-time representing 2007-09-23 ( 7 years ago)?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to print your before. Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // java.util.Calendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar(2007, 9 - 1, 23);
  // Current time would be....
  java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
  // ^------ The current time.
  System.out.println("Before: " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
  // v------ Add five seconds
  cal.add(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 5);
  System.out.println("After: " + cal.getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Outputs before (with a fixed date)

```
Before: 1190520000000
After: 1190520005000
```

Outputs now (with current time)

```
Before: 1390789209073
After: 1390789214073
```

Comment: yes but I will get this result every time ! I need the exact time. Maybe I have to use getInstance ? I edited my post can you please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
Date d1= initDate();//initialise your date to any date 
Date d2 = new Date(d1.getTime() + 5 * 1000 ); //add 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fixed Moment In Time

You seem to be confused about the nature of the java.util.Date & java.util.Calendar classes. They represent a fixed moment in the timeline of the Universe, not an ongoing moving clock.

The computer (and therefore your [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)) already has a physical clock tracking ongoing time. The Date & Calendar classes ask that physical clock for the current time and then record that moment. Or the classes re-create a moment from the past (or future). But the date and time stored in a Date/Calendar instance does not change, does not roll forward with the clock.

## Timer

If you are looking to fire some event at a certain time, see the [Timer class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) bundled with Java.

## Joda-Time

By the way, the java.util.Date & java.util.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. For years now, the third-party open-source [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library has served as a popular substitute.

Joda-Time is similar to Date/Calendar classes in that a `DateTime` represents a fixed moment on the timeline. Internally, both java.util.Date and Joda-Time keep a long integer, the number of milliseconds since the beginning of 1970 (the Unix [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)) in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)/GMT (no time zone offset). A DateTime stores that number **and** a time zone offset.

```
DateTime now = new DateTime(); // Current date-time in default time zone.
```

Generally better to specify a time zone…

```
DateTime nowInBoston = new DateTime( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" ) );
```

Represent a moment in the past…

```
DateTime aMomentInThePastInBoston = new DateTime( 2007, 9, 23, 13, 14, 15, DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" ) );
```

Joda-Time is mostly immutable (for thread-safety). So we create new instances rather than change the data inside an existing instance. Let's take that instance created above and create a new one for the same date and time zone but setting its time-of-day to the first moment of the day (usually that means a time of 00:00:00)…

```
DateTime firstMomentOfThatPastDayInBoston = aMomentInThePastInBoston.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

When you execute this code, each DateTime instance sits in memory. Their date-time value (that long integer) remains the same.

If you want to extract the number of milliseconds since epoch (perhaps that what you meant by "timestamp"), call the [`getMillis`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis%28%29) method…

```
long millisSinceEpoch = firstMomentOfThatPastDayInBoston.getMillis(); // Use 'long' not 'int'!
```

Be wary of using such integer-based "timestamps". Different programming languages, libraries, database engines, file systems, and other systems use various counts ( seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds ) with various epochs (Unix-style of January 1, 1970 is not the only epoch). Passing around a raw integer value can get tricky.

If you need a java.util.Date for use with other classes, convert…

```
java.util.Date date = firstMomentOfThatPastDayInBoston.toDate();
```

Search StackOverflow for "joda" to find many more examples.

## Java 8

In Java 8, a new [java.time.* package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) is bundled with the Java platform. These new classes are defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), supplant the old bundled classes, and are inspired by Joda-Time.